# Cómo transformar las columnas de un CSV en Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

Tengo un archivo CSV. Por ejemplo éste:

```
animales;numeros;nombres;
leon;21,5;Paula;
perro;32,4;Guillermo;
zebra;44;Elena;
gorila;100,4;Pepe;
```

Me gustaría guardar cada columna de mi CSV en un array.

Por ejemplo:

```
let animales = ['animales', 'leon', 'perro', 'zebra', 'gorila'];
let numeros = ['numeros', 21.5, 32.4, 44, 100.4];
let nombres = ['nombres', 'Paula', 'Guillermo', 'Elena', 'Pepe'];
```

El CSV lo recibo desde un `fetch` a una API REST y está guardado en un `sessionStorage` bajo el nombre `datos`.

Ya que necesito poder elegir la columna con la que deseo trabajar más tarde, ¿cómo podría realizar esto?

Comment: Leyendo de nuevo tu pregunta, ¿deseas también el código de conversión de CSV a datos de javascript?

Comment: si, lo que me gustaría es transformar el csv que pongo de ejemplo al array que pongo como ejemplo, el problema es que no me aclaro mucho con el código para transformarlo, he estado buscando información al respecto pero todos recogen el csv desde un archivo subido de un usuario y se me esta haciendo una montaña realizarlo de este modo

Comment: Hecho. Mira la última edición de mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás olvidando poner entre comillas las cadenas de caracteres:

```
let animales = ['animales', 'leon', 'perro', 'zebra', 'gorila'];
let numeros = ['numeros', 21.5, 32.4, 44, 100.4];
let nombres = ['nombres', 'Paula', 'Guillermo', 'Elena', 'Pepe'];
```

Aunque yo te recomendaría almacenarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
datos = {
    'animales': [ 'leon', 'perro', 'zebra', 'gorila' ],
    'numeros': [ 21.5, 32.4, 44, 100.4 ],
    'nombres': [ 'Paula', 'Guillermo', 'Elena', 'Pepe' ],
};
```

Fíjate que he eliminado la primera fila de cada resultado y, además, he usado el nombre de columna como nombre de la propiedad.

Ejemplo:

```js
/* Datos obtenidos del servicio web */
let datos_crudos = `animales;numeros;nombres;
leon;21,5;Paula;
perro;32,4;Guillermo;
zebra;44;Elena;
gorila;100,4;Pepe;`;

/* Elementos separados por líneas */
let datos_separados = datos_crudos.split('\n');

/* Obtengo el primero para conocer los nombres de las columnas */
let cabeceras = datos_separados.shift().split(';');

/* Predefinimos la salida y sus propiedades */
let datos = {};
cabeceras.forEach(cabecera => {
  datos[cabecera] = [];
});

/* Iteramos por el resto de datos */
while (elementos = datos_separados.shift()) {
  /* Iterams cada elemento del registro */
  elementos.split(';').forEach((elemento, indice) => {
    /* Lo agregamos a la cabecera dada por su índice */
    datos[cabeceras[indice]].push(elemento);
  });
}

/* Mostramos el resultado */
console.log(datos);
```

Comment: verdad lo de las comillas disculpa, hice el ejemplo rápidamente y no me di cuenta

Comment: Ahora he incluido código de ejemplo para generar la salida propuesta a partir de los datos de entrada proporcionados.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!! es mas sencillo de lo que pensaba vi codigos un poco dificiles y estaba tratando de hacerlo de ese modo pero era todo como una mancha que no podía arreglar. Se transformaria en un json cierto??